# Erlang: Printing out specific value in list

Tags: list, printing, erlang, output

If I have a list for example:

```
[{list1, [1,2]},{list2, [3,4]}]
```

How would I print out [3,4] using io:format if this is passed in as a variable, for example I.

I'm currently doing:

```
io:format("list 2: ~w~n", [I]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example list is in the form: `[{Key1, Value1}, {Key2, Value2}, ...]`, where Key is an atom. This kind of list can also be called a *proplist* (property list). The module named `proplist`, can handle exactly this datastructure.

In your case, you could just run:

```
PList = [{list1, [1,2]},{list2, [3,4]}],
Value = proplists:get_value(list2, PList),
io:format("list2: ~p~n", [Value]).
```

The variable `Value` is now bound to the value `[3,4]`.

See also: [The Erlang-Documentation page for proplists](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html)

Comment: @Scott: How do you try to print the Value? If I run it on the console, it works quite adequateley.

Comment: It was a typo on my end, solution works great thanks